# using dplyr filter_at() function to select rows with conditions

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I want to filter data frame according to a specific conditions in several columns.

I use the following example o make it my statement more clear.

I have a data frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(122, 122, 122), B = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), 
                  C = c(5, 5, 4), D = c(6, 7, 6))
```

I want to select rows which contains both maximum values in column C and D, my R code is :

```
select <- dat %>%
          group_by(A, B) %>%
          filter(C == max(C) , D == max(D))
```

and I get want I want:

```
> select
# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   A, B [1]
     A     B     C     D
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   122   0.1     5     7
```

However, I want to use `filter_at()` function

```
select <- dat %>%
          group_by(A, B) %>%
          filter_at(vars(C, D), all_vars(. max))
```

It did not work. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
dat %>%
    group_by(A, B) %>%
    filter_at(vars(C, D), all_vars(. == max(.)))
```

The problem before was `all_vars()` is expecting to evaluate to a logical. And without an equality operator, `==`, `>`, `<`, it was throwing an error back at you.

Comment: and what if I wanted to filter by two conditions? Like, ```filter_at (vars(C, D), all_vars(. == max(.)) && vars (A,B), any_vars (. > 120))``` ? (just a random example)

Comment: I don't think that will work, b/c the second argument, `.vars_predicate` expects a single quoted predicate expression. Instead using a follow on `filter_at` like this will get the same AND behavior `... %>% filter_at(vars(C, D), all_vars(. == max(.))) %>% filter_at(vars (A,B), any_vars (. > 120))`

Answer (score 0):

As of dplyr 1.0, there is a new way to select, filter and mutate. This is accomplished with the `across` function and certain helper verbs. For this particular case, the filtering could also be accomplished as follows:

```
dat %>%
group_by(A, B) %>%
filter(across(c(C, D), ~ . == max(.)))

# A tibble: 1 x 4
# Groups:   A, B [1]
      A     B     C     D
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   122   0.1     5     7
```